# Spring Integration with IBM MQ Series

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Am novice when it comes to Spring integration and so had some questions around it.
Am trying to integrate Spring Integration with the MQ Series and believe that all my IBM MQ(Q Connection Factory and Queue) entries should be going inside my applicationcontext.xml file.
I have the applicationcontext file for ActiveMQ Implementation and just wanted to know what exactly an IBM MQ specific entries in App Contest file will look like. Questions are -

1. Do I need to have an MQ Series installed on the same machine where I
   am running my Spring Application.

   2. I presume not, then what should be the entries for QueueConnectionFactory and Destination attributes
      in the ApplicationContext file.
      providing some sample poc's will help me lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create beans like this

> ```
> jms.transportType=1
> jms.queueManager=YOUR_QUEUE_MANAGER
> jms.hostName=YOUR_HOSTNAME
> jms.port=1321
>
> jms.channel=YOUR_CHANNEL
> jms.receiver.queue.name=YOUR_QUEUE
> jms.username=
> jms.alias=
> jms.mq.connection.factory=jmsConnectionFactory
> jms.mq.receiver.queue=receiverQueue
> ```

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="${jms.transportType}"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="${jms.queueManager}"/>
    <property name="hostName" value="${jms.hostName}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${jms.port}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${jms.channel}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="secureJmsConnectionAdapter" class="yourpackages.SecureJMSConnectionAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="${jms.mq.connection.factory}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${jms.username}"/>
    <property name="pwdAlias" value="${jms.alias}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="receiverQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${jms.queueManager}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${jms.receiver.queue.name}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="receiverJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="secureJmsConnectionAdapter" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="${jms.mq.receiver.queue}"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="secureJmsConnectionAdapter" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${jms.receiver.queue.name}" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="mQListener" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Till creating **jmsConnectionFactory** and "receiverQueue". It is working for  me. Next my requirement is, i'm using jmsConnectionFactory as below using spring integration. <br/> <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
  id="jmsInAdapter" connection-factory="esbQueueConnectionFactory"
  destination="inQueue" channel="readFromChannel" />

 <bean id="msgProcesser" class="com.gap.si.service.MessageProcessService" />

 <int:service-activator id="servAct"
  input-channel="readFromChannel" ref="msgProcesser" method="processMessage" />. <br/> But i want to mention in java 7 DSL. <br/> Any on this.

Comment: Could you please close this question and open another? Because our discussion will be offtop and not useful for searching inside of stackoferflow.

Comment: @OleksandrLoushkin would you know what all dependencies (jars) are reuired for this setup?