# IBM MQ and Spring Integration - security settings

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq

I've got a Spring Integration flow which uses an inbound gateway to get messages from an IBM MQ queue:

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="InputGateway"  
   request-destination="RequestQueue"  
         request-channel="RequestChannel"
         reply-channel="ReplyChannel"     
         />
```

However I'm not capable of assigning security settings. In particular, I need an username, password and userAuthenticationMQCSP = false (for reasons beyond the scope of this post, I won't get into details but my broker will throw a MQRC = 2009 otherwise).

I've followed the [IBM guide to connect with jmsTemplate](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/) and works just fine. This uses the official [Spring boot starter from IBM MQ](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring/blob/master/mq-jms-spring-boot-starter) which will kindly create a connection factory and will autoconfigure it with some defaults from application.properties:

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=myQMName
ibm.mq.channel=myChannel
ibm.mq.connName=myhostname(myPort)
ibm.mq.user=username
ibm.mq.password=*******
ibm.mq.userAuthenticationMQCSP=false
```

Now, back to the Spring Integration case. According to the [int-jms:inbound-gateway spec](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/html/jms.html), a connectionFactory will be injected to the gateway, by name (attribute: connection-factory) which is set up to be "jmsConnectionFactory" by default

> By default, all of the JMS adapters that require a reference to the
>   ConnectionFactory automatically look for a bean named
>   jmsConnectionFactory. That is why you do not see a connection-factory
>   attribute in many of the examples. However, if your JMS
>   ConnectionFactory has a different bean name, you need to provide that
>   attribute.

I don't see any way to set up a predictable name for the connection factory that I can plug into the int-jms:inbound-gateway.

Now, taking a different approach, as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299757/spring-integration-with-ibm-mq-series/58032981#58032981) I've created my connectionFactory with an adecuate name:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
     <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
     <property name="queueManager" value="myQMName"/>
     <property name="hostName" value="myhostname"/>
     <property name="port" value="myPort" />
     <property name="channel" value="myChannel"/>
</bean>
```

But now I need somewhere to put the credentials and the security parameters. Looking at the example above, it looks like I need to plug something like:

```
<bean id="secureJmsConnectionAdapter" class="**yourpackages.SecureJMSConnectionAdapter**">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="${jms.mq.connection.factory}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${jms.username}"/>
    <property name="pwdAlias" value="${jms.alias}"/>
</bean>
```

However it is unclear to me how to implement this SecureJMSConnectionAdapter.

Additionally, if I set up my own connection factory, I will lose all of MQ boot starter automagic thanks to this annotation on the [MQAutoConfiguration class](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring/blob/master/mq-jms-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/com/ibm/mq/spring/boot/MQAutoConfiguration.java):

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value=javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.class)
```

Any ideas on how to put these pieces together?

EDIT: Just to avoid any possible red herrings to anyone, the MQRC2009 was irrelevant to ibm.mq.userAuthenticationMQCSP=false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of my old projects I used a bean like this:

```
<bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jms.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jms.alias}"/>
</bean>
```

Should work well as a wrapper for your `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory`, but you have to use this `jmsQueueConnectionFactory` in the target components.

Although it looks like the mentioned *IBM MQ JMS Spring* doesn't that for us properly exposing a `jmsConnectionFactory` bean. You can rely on the default from Spring Integration in this case or use that `jmsConnectionFactory` explicitly for the `connection-factory`.

Also with Spring Boot you should consider to go away from XML configuration and give a chance for Spring Integration Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#java-dsl

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for.